# Directory Searcher Exception

Tags: c#, .net

I have written following code to search directory but `Searcher.FindOne();` i got exception `[Unknown error (0x80005000)]`

```
bool Success = false;

System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry Entry = 
   new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + Domain, Username, Password);

System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher Searcher = 
   new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(Entry);

Searcher.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.OneLevel;
try
{
     System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult Results = Searcher.FindOne();
     Success = (Results != null);
}
catch
{
     Success = false;
}
return Success;
```

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2428673

Comment: You are catching all the valuable exceptions and throwing it away. Try catching and logging the exception.

Comment: Is that all you got out of your exception object? (which should be at `catch (Exception ex)`  )

Comment: What value does `Domain` hold? Also: you should catch the exception (`catch (Exception ex)`) and then inspect the contents of the exception - what does it tell you (in detail, including all the `.InnerException` details)?